# バッジ授与者の一覧表示がおかしい

Tags: バグ, 完了

たとえば、

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer

が例に上げられますが、授与先の名前の上に「14分前 回授与されました」などと表示されています
（回数は表示されていません）

Comment: すみませんが、もうちょっと問題を説明してくれませんか？レイアウトがおかしいですか？英語版は日本語と同じに見えます：http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer

Comment: 「N回」表示された、と出て良いと思うのですが、回数が出ていないようにも見えます。なので、「14分前 1回授与されました」と出て欲しいのですが、回数が全く表示されていないのかなと思います。

Comment: なるほど！理解ができました。「授与されました」が「回授与されました」になっていますね。ちょっと確認してみます。